# Javascript Intl.DateTimeFormat hours12 gives odd output on Chrome

Tags: javascript, datetime

I'm seeing behavior on Chrome where the return value for a 12:00 pm time formatted with hours12 set to true comes out as 0 pm. Shouldn't it be 12? If not, what's the proper way to display a 12 hour clock? Note that I'm constrained to using ES5.

The following in Chrome prints 0 pm:

```js
var foo = new Date(2020, 0, 1, 12, 0, 0)
var bar = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-GB", {hour12: true, hour: "numeric"}).format(foo)
console.log(bar)
```

Note that the value of bar is '0 pm'. Other languages besides en-GB exhibit this behavior. The same code run with en-US, though, gives me '12 PM'. Is it that the British and others actually use '0 pm' to indicate noon? Is this a bug in Chrome? It does not happen in FF or IE.

Thanks in advance for any input.

Answer (score 12):

Not sure if you're still looking for a solution... I had the same problem too but found that using `hourCycle: 'h12'` worked instead of `hour12: true`

Answer (score 3):

This is likely an issue with hour cycle. It's supposed to be based on the supplied language code and should be overridden by setting the ["hc" option](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat) to one of "h11", "h12", "h23", "h24".

However, Chrome seems to ignore the hour cycle anyway:

```js
var foo = new Date(2020, 0, 1, 12, 0, 0)
var bar = new Intl.DateTimeFormat("en-GB", {
  hour12: true,
  hour: "numeric",
  hc: "h12" // Should force 12 am / 12 pm
}).format(foo);

console.log(bar); // 0 pm in Chrome, 12 pm in others
```

[According to MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/DateTimeFormat/DateTimeFormat), if both *hour12* and *hc* options are set, then *hour12* takes precedence. However, removing the *hour12* option and setting `hc:"12"` returns just "12", without the "pm" and midnight is "00".

The Intl object doesn't specify what format languages map to, it's left up to individual implementations to work out what a particular language or culture uses. So you can use trial and error to find a language code that does the job, e.g. in this case using just "en" rather than "en-GB" returns 12 pm in Chrome.

As far as I can see, the Intl object is not suitable for formatting dates. It's really only good for conveniently getting the date parts using the *formatToParts* method then formatting manually from there. It's also handy for getting dates and times in timezones based on IANA locations, but you can't expect it to properly or consistently format dates across different implementations just based on the language code.

Comment: Hi Rob. Thanks for the input. The problem I have is that our front end code is used all over the world, and we're letting Javascript format dates in a manner a particular user is accustomed to. If I pick my own, then I have to format the date myself(eg equivalent of 'AM' or 'PM' to languages that don't use AM or PM). It becomes a nightmare of localization that I'd rather let the browser handle. I may just have to put a check for the '0' in the output and change the 0 to a 12 in those cases.

Comment: I don't trust the Intl object to format dates. Far better to use an unambiguous format that is consistent with the surrounding information. I can't really say more without knowing how your code is used, but be very wary of allowing the format to be dictated by a language code when you don't know exactly what the result will be.

Comment: According to the ES5 interfaces our code uses, neither hourCycle nor hc are defined. I'd love it if they were because just setting h12 without setting hour12 solves my problem. But I can't use that. So this is looking like just a bug in chrome.