# convert 12-hour hh:mm AM/PM to 24-hour hh:mm depending on toLocaleTimeString()

Tags: javascript, datetime, localization

I have some opening hour information on my website/database in the hh:mm AM/PM format and would love to convert it to  24-hour hh:mm if the users browser language settings prefers that format instead of the AM/PM format.

I heard this is possible with Javascript's **.toLocaleTimeString()**.
Who could help me with a function?

given e.g.

```
var time = '11:30am to 3pm, 5 to 9pm';
```

would love to get the output / rewrite it to

```
var time = '11:30 to 15:00, 17:00 to 21:00';
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function timeToLocale(hours, minutes, locale=[]) {
  var time = new Date();
  time.setHours(hours, minutes);
  return time.toLocaleTimeString(locale,{timeStyle: 'short'});
}

var time;

time = timeToLocale(11,30)+" to "+
       timeToLocale(15, 0)+", "  +
       timeToLocale(17, 0)+" to "+
       timeToLocale(21, 0);
console.log(time);

time = timeToLocale(11,30,"en-US")+" to "+
       timeToLocale(15, 0,"en-US")+", "  +
       timeToLocale(17, 0,"en-US")+" to "+
       timeToLocale(21, 0,"en-US");
console.log(time);

time = timeToLocale(11,30,"en-IL")+" to "+
       timeToLocale(15, 0,"en-IL")+", "  +
       timeToLocale(17, 0,"en-IL")+" to "+
       timeToLocale(21, 0,"en-IL");
console.log(time);
```

Don't specify `locale` - It's in the snippet for demonstration purpose = use the format of the first setting of `time` = without `locale`.
Do specify time in 24-hours format, and minutes.

---

I'm in Israel, yet browser uses "en-US", so here's a "way" to force it to use, in my case, "en-IL":
I've use the first word of a country's name, seems ok.
I'm using Chrome on Windows 10 - might need adjustments for cross-platform and/or cross-browser.
Also, it assumes user's language is English.
Sheesh!!!

```js
var codeByCountry={"Afghanistan":"AF","Aland":"AX","Albania":"AL","Algeria":"DZ","American":"AS","Andorra":"AD","Angola":"AO","Anguilla":"AI","Antarctica":"AQ","Antigua":"AG","Argentina":"AR","Armenia":"AM","Aruba":"AW","Australia":"AU","Austria":"AT","Azerbaijan":"AZ","Bahamas":"BS","Bahrain":"BH","Bangladesh":"BD","Barbados":"BB","Belarus":"BY","Belgium":"BE","Belize":"BZ","Benin":"BJ","Bermuda":"BM","Bhutan":"BT","Bolivia":"BO","Bosnia":"BA","Botswana":"BW","Bouvet":"BV","Brazil":"BR","British":"IO","Brunei":"BN","Bulgaria":"BG","Burkina":"BF","Burundi":"BI","Cambodia":"KH","Cameroon":"CM","Canada":"CA","Cape":"CV","Cayman":"KY","Central":"CF","Chad":"TD","Chile":"CL","China":"CN","Christmas":"CX","Cocos":"CC","Colombia":"CO","Comoros":"KM","Congo":"CG","Congo,":"CD","Cook":"CK","Costa":"CR","Cote":"CI","Croatia":"HR","Cuba":"CU","Cyprus":"CY","Czech":"CZ","Denmark":"DK","Djibouti":"DJ","Dominica":"DM","Dominican":"DO","Ecuador":"EC","Egypt":"EG","El":"SV","Equatorial":"GQ","Eritrea":"ER","Estonia":"EE","Ethiopia":"ET","Falkland":"FK","Faroe":"FO","Fiji":"FJ","Finland":"FI","France":"FR","French":"TF","Gabon":"GA","Gambia":"GM","Georgia":"GE","Germany":"DE","Ghana":"GH","Gibraltar":"GI","Greece":"GR","Greenland":"GL","Grenada":"GD","Guadeloupe":"GP","Guam":"GU","Guatemala":"GT","Guernsey":"GG","Guinea":"GN","Guinea-Bissau":"GW","Guyana":"GY","Haiti":"HT","Heard":"HM","Holy":"VA","Honduras":"HN","Hong":"HK","Hungary":"HU","Iceland":"IS","India":"IN","Indonesia":"ID","Iran,":"IR","Iraq":"IQ","Ireland":"IE","Isle":"IM","Israel":"IL","Italy":"IT","Jamaica":"JM","Japan":"JP","Jersey":"JE","Jordan":"JO","Kazakhstan":"KZ","Kenya":"KE","Kiribati":"KI","Korea":"KR","Kuwait":"KW","Kyrgyzstan":"KG","Lao":"LA","Latvia":"LV","Lebanon":"LB","Lesotho":"LS","Liberia":"LR","Libyan":"LY","Liechtenstein":"LI","Lithuania":"LT","Luxembourg":"LU","Macao":"MO","Macedonia":"MK","Madagascar":"MG","Malawi":"MW","Malaysia":"MY","Maldives":"MV","Mali":"ML","Malta":"MT","Marshall":"MH","Martinique":"MQ","Mauritania":"MR","Mauritius":"MU","Mayotte":"YT","Mexico":"MX","Micronesia,":"FM","Moldova":"MD","Monaco":"MC","Mongolia":"MN","Montenegro":"ME","Montserrat":"MS","Morocco":"MA","Mozambique":"MZ","Myanmar":"MM","Namibia":"NA","Nauru":"NR","Nepal":"NP","Netherlands":"AN","New":"NZ","Nicaragua":"NI","Niger":"NE","Nigeria":"NG","Niue":"NU","Norfolk":"NF","Northern":"MP","Norway":"NO","Oman":"OM","Pakistan":"PK","Palau":"PW","Palestinian":"PS","Panama":"PA","Papua":"PG","Paraguay":"PY","Peru":"PE","Philippines":"PH","Pitcairn":"PN","Poland":"PL","Portugal":"PT","Puerto":"PR","Qatar":"QA","Reunion":"RE","Romania":"RO","Russian":"RU","Rwanda":"RW","Saint":"VC","Samoa":"WS","San":"SM","Sao":"ST","Saudi":"SA","Senegal":"SN","Serbia":"RS","Seychelles":"SC","Sierra":"SL","Singapore":"SG","Slovakia":"SK","Slovenia":"SI","Solomon":"SB","Somalia":"SO","South":"GS","Spain":"ES","Sri":"LK","Sudan":"SD","Suriname":"SR","Svalbard":"SJ","Swaziland":"SZ","Sweden":"SE","Switzerland":"CH","Syrian":"SY","Taiwan":"TW","Tajikistan":"TJ","Tanzania":"TZ","Thailand":"TH","Timor-Leste":"TL","Togo":"TG","Tokelau":"TK","Tonga":"TO","Trinidad":"TT","Tunisia":"TN","Turkey":"TR","Turkmenistan":"TM","Turks":"TC","Tuvalu":"TV","Uganda":"UG","Ukraine":"UA","United":"UM","Uruguay":"UY","Uzbekistan":"UZ","Vanuatu":"VU","Venezuela":"VE","Viet":"VN","Virgin":"VI","Wallis":"WF","Western":"EH","Yemen":"YE","Zambia":"ZM","Zimbabwe":"ZW"};

var language=navigator.language.split("-")[0];
var country=(new Date).toString().split("(")[1].split(" ")[0];
var code=codeByCountry[country];
var languageAndCode=language+"-"+code;

function timeToLocale(hours, minutes, locale) {
  if(locale==undefined) locale=languageAndCode;
  var time = new Date();
  time.setHours(hours, minutes);
  return time.toLocaleTimeString(locale,{timeStyle: 'short'});
}

var time;

time = timeToLocale(11,30)+" to "+
       timeToLocale(15, 0)+", "  +
       timeToLocale(17, 0)+" to "+
       timeToLocale(21, 0);
console.log(time);

time = timeToLocale(11,30,"en-US")+" to "+
       timeToLocale(15, 0,"en-US")+", "  +
       timeToLocale(17, 0,"en-US")+" to "+
       timeToLocale(21, 0,"en-US");
console.log(time);

time = timeToLocale(11,30,"en-IL")+" to "+
       timeToLocale(15, 0,"en-IL")+", "  +
       timeToLocale(17, 0,"en-IL")+" to "+
       timeToLocale(21, 0,"en-IL");
console.log(time);
```

Comment: For me throws an error: "RangeError: invalid language tag: en-undefined".

Comment: @RobG, the second snippet (or, did you copy to your system)?  What language is your computer/browser using?  What browser?  What operating system?  I did say it might give problems

Comment: Consider a browser set to Spanish on a system set to a New Zealand timezone, is "es-NZ" a valid language code? How would the timezone name look? Timezone names aren't standardised, may not contain the country name (e.g. Pacific Standard Time) and aren't required to be part of the value produced by Date.prototype.toString. So any browser on a system set to a timezone that doesn't usually contain a country name.

Comment: Just use the first snippet and hope for the best, then...
I just tried to force my preference of 24-hour format and in Israel while my browser insists I'm "en-US".

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Date, set it to the time and use *Date.prototype.toLocaleString* with the default language and appropriate time options. That will format the time according to the browser language settings, but may nor may not be a format that the user prefers or expects though.

It's simpler if the time is passed to the function in 24 hour format.

The following creates a date for 1 Jan 2000 (it could be any date) and uses UTC to ensure it avoids daylight saving transition times where it's possible to create a time that occurs twice or not at all, leading to unexpected results.

The language will set the hour cycle and whether it's 12 or 24 hour. Note that in some cases the browser will get it wrong, e.g. [Javascript Intl.DateTimeFormat hours12 gives odd output on Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63273543/javascript-intl-datetimeformat-hours12-gives-odd-output-on-chrome/63274115#63274115).

```js
/**
 * Return time string based on browser default language
 *
 * @param {number} hr: hour of time in 24 hour format
 * @param {number} min: minute of time
 * @returns {string} time formatted for browser default language
 */
function timeAsBrowserDefaultLanguage(hr, min) {
  let d = new Date(Date.UTC(2000,0,1,hr,min));
  return d.toLocaleString('default',{
    hour: 'numeric',
    minute: 'numeric',
    timeZone: 'UTC'
  });
}

console.log(timeAsBrowserDefaultLanguage(20,15));
```

Comment: Your answer is the opposite of what is asked for. "Because it's simpler" is hardly a reason to not answer a question

Answer (score 0):

```
formatto24(date) {
    const ampm = date.split(' ')[1];
    const time = date.split(' ')[0];
    const [hours, minutes, seconds] = time.split(':');
    if (ampm === 'pm') {
      const hours24 = JSON.parse(hours) + 12;
      return `${hours24}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    }
    if (ampm === 'am' && hours === '12') {
      const hours24 = `0${JSON.parse(hours) - 12}`;
      return `${hours24}:${minutes}:${seconds}`;
    }
    return time;
  }
```

Comment: Why do you use `JSON.parse(hours)`? Then, three lines below, you do it again, but only if hours is 12, yet you subtract the 12 dynamically although, it'll always be 0 (12 - 12).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).